# How to show data inserted by ckeditor in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, ckeditor

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 project and I am using ckeditor in my project to insert data to SQL Server. When I go to user pages to see data inserted by ckeditor I see html tags in the pages like below .please help me to solve this problem

```
<h2 style="font-style:italic;"><strong>Hello</strong></h2> <p><strong>How Are You</strong></p>


[ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult InsertAboutConfirm(aboutu a, HttpPostedFileBase img)
    {
        if (img != null)
        {
            Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
            img.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" +g.ToString()+ img.FileName));
            a.img = g.ToString()  + img.FileName;
        }
        db._AboutusRepository.InsertItem(a);
        TempData["result"] = "اطلاعات شما بدرستی ثبت شد";
        return RedirectToAction("InsertAbout");
    }
```

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvj3O.png)

I load the data in model

```
 <div class="container padding-top">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <!-- Widget Text-->
                        <div class="panel-box">
                            <div class="titles">
                                <h4>درباره ما</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <div class="col-md-12" style=" font-family:'B Nazanin'">
                               @if (Model != null)
                               {
                                   @Model.matn
                               }

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Widget Text-->
                    </div>
```

[See AboutUs page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9dLY.png)

Comment: How you are assigning the value to ckeditor. PLease show some code.

Comment: I have a ckeditor in my admin view to insert data.and I type words in this control and save it

Comment: HOw you load data in it ? Show that code please.

Comment: Please add the code in question not in comments.